# Moving the onscreen keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I have a touch screen application written in WPF.  I need to use the on screen keyboard to populate a text box.  I start the osk.exe process when the text box gains focus and it works fine.  I'm wondering if I can move the keyboard around so it's default position doesn't cover the text box.

If I can't do it with osk.exe (included in Windows 7), is there a third party on screen keyboard which I can?

Comment: Some links to investigate: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/145579/A-Software-Virtual-Keyboard-for-Your-WPF-Apps  ... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32568/A-Touch-Screen-Keyboard-Control-in-WPF ... http://wosk.codeplex.com/  .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168203/incorporating-the-windows-7-onscreen-keyboard-into-a-wpf-app

Comment: You should not start osk all by yourself. Windows should do this for you if you configured it as tablet or touch device. I think if windows 7 detects a pen device all of this will work automagically.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit: How can I make Windows think that it is a touch device?