# WPF ScrollViewer not working with touch

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, windows-8.1, .net-4.6

I have a WPF application running on a Windows 8.1 tablet using touch. After a whole lot of reading about how to solve some common touch specific problems I found [this tutorial](http://brianlagunas.com/showing-windows-8-touch-keyboard-wpf/) that really pointed me in the right direction.
My problem is that after implementing the tutorial my `ScrollViewer` stopped working unless I scroll directly from the scroll bar itself.
this is how my `ScrollViewer` (which is the top element in my window) looks like:

```
<ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" PanningMode="Both">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="48"
                       Text="{Binding SelectedView.ViewHeader}"
                       TextAlignment="Center"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            <Separator Margin="0,25" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"
                          Margin="10,0,0,30"
                          Content="{Binding SelectedView}" />
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it?
**EDIT:**
The reason I chose the method above over the one suggested above is because it eliminated many controls focus problems I was having such as `textboxes` the need 2 or 3 touches to receive focus or `comboboxes` that stay open after selecting an item:
[image: combobox touch problem]

Answer (score 0):

When using this method DisableWPFTabletSupport. You are disabling all tablet support which include ScrollViewer Touch screen. See my post in this link to achieve similar behavior (show/hide windows keyboard) without disabling tablet support.

[Show & hiding the Windows 8 on screen keyboard from WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090325/show-hiding-the-windows-8-on-screen-keyboard-from-wpf/31886209#31886209)

Comment: please see my edit on why I chose this approach over the one you suggested.

Comment: Hi Yoav, I'm using Telerik for my control (telerik:RadComboBox) in my wpf application which inherits wpf combobox and I don't have the behaviour that you explain... in my application.

Comment: I tried with combobox and normal window and I cant replicate your current behaviour (I'm using a windows surface).